# appendTo is not working with each in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to apply animation on each "div". But it is applying just in first one not in all.
According to me "$("#viewport").each(appendTo(c));" this line is not working in javascript code.

HTML code:

```
         <div id="viewport"></div>
         <div id="viewport"></div>
         <div id="viewport"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function () {
            var a = 0;
            for (; a < 15; a += 1) {
                setTimeout(function b() {
                    var a = Math.random() * 1e3 + 5e3,
                    c = $("<div />", {
                    "class": "smoke",
                    css: {
                        opacity: 0,
                        left: Math.random() * 200 + 80
                    }
                });
                    **$("#viewport").each(appendTo(c));**
                    $.when($(c).animate({
                        opacity: 1
                        }, {
                        duration: a / 4,
                        easing: "linear",
                        queue: false,
                        complete: function () {
                            $(c).animate({
                                opacity: 0
                                }, {
                                duration: a / 3,
                                easing: "linear",
                                queue: false
                            })
                        }
                        }), $(c).animate({
                        bottom: $("#viewport").height()
                        }, {
                        duration: a,
                        easing: "linear",
                        queue: false
                        })).then(function () {
                        $(c).remove();
                        b()
                    });
            }, Math.random() * 3e3)
        }
}());
    });
```

Comment: That's not how [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) works: it takes a function as argument. Check your browser console for errors (F12).

Comment: why you give same id for all div , please use common class for all div

Comment: Because animation is same for all div. That's why I gave same id for all. Ok if you say so I update.

Comment: I have checked my browser console and that is showing this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: appendTo is not defined"

Comment: `appendTo()` is called on an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong. You want something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="viewport">
  <div class="smoke smoke1"></div>
  <div class="smoke smoke2"></div>
  <div class="smoke smoke3"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

$('#viewport .smoke').each(function ns () {
  var initialTop = $(this).position().top;

  $(this).animate({
    top: - $(this).height()
  }, Math.random() * 2000 + 2000, function () {
    $(this).css({
      top: initialTop,
      opacity: 0
    });
  }).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, ns)
});
}());
```

CSS:

```
#viewport {
    position: relative;

    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;

    margin: 100px auto;
    border: 1px solid #333333;

    overflow: hidden;
}
#viewport .smoke {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#viewport .smoke1 {
    left: 140px;
    top: 260px;
}
#viewport .smoke2 {
    left: 180px;
    top: 260px;
}
#viewport .smoke3 {
    left: 220px;
    top: 260px;
}
```

Please see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/1rf31eyL/

You may check another example demo here: http://gettycreations.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use more than one element with the same id is absolutely bad practice! Put "vieport" as class and use

```
$( ".viewport" )
```

The .each() function take a function as first argument and in that function context, the "this" variable will contain the element

```
 $( ".viewport" ).each( function() {
    $( this ).appendTo( c );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all

add function in $.each

like

```
"$("#viewport").each(
function(){
$(this).appendTo(c);
}
);
```

and then try this,

```
$("[id=viewport]")
```

When you use

```
$("#viewport")
```

it selects only the first element with the given ID.

However, when you select by attribute (e.g. id in your case), it returns all matching elements, like so:

```
$("[id=viewport]")
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this bad practice: even though that may work, `id` is supposed to be [unique in a DOMDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id).

Comment: He must also have separate ids for each element or use class

Comment: yes i know that it is a bad practice and i also commented same , but in case if it is the need so this will be useful